# SQL Negative with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

Im having a doubt in SQL statement where i have negation condition using 2 fields using the sample below:

```
COLUMN A | COLUMN B
  TRA    |   ORIG
  TRA    |   ORIG
  TERM   |    _N
  TRA    |   ORIG
ORIG-REV1|    _N
ORIG-REV2|    _N
```

im trying get filter the conditions where

```
"COLUMN B"='_N' and "COLUMN  A" in ('ORIG-REV1','ORIG-REV2').
```

Currently im using the condition

```
"COLUMN B" <>'_N' and ("COLUMN  A" <> 'ORIG-REV1' or "COLUMN  A" <> 'ORIG-REV2')
```

but this condition is filtering me the record where "COLUMN A"=TERM because COLUMN_B value  is '_N'

the OUTPUT i needed is:

```
COLUMN A | COLUMN B
  TRA    |   ORIG
  TRA    |   ORIG
  TERM   |    _N
  TRA    |   ORIG
```

i know in postgres i just need to use Not("COLUMN B"='_N' and "COLUMN  A" in ('ORIG-REV1','ORIG-REV2')), unfortunately the technology im using is very old and rudimentary and not doesn't even exist (only =, <>, >, <, OR, IN, LIKE). is there a way to get this filter in another way?

Best Regards,
Paulo Serra

Comment: What technology are you using that doesn't support not()? Does it support CASE statements, or the equivalent, at least? You could do it like that.

Comment: Sorry i miss the OR condition. This one exist. Its call SEARCH only exist in old Telco RA software.

Comment: I find it unlikely that there is no logical NOT operator. It may be `!` or `~` or something else, but logical not has been in the ANSI standard since the 1980s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, deleted my comment thinking I'd made a logical flub. All good.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/-hbQem22

It's SQL Server, but hopefully that tool your are using isn't so limited that the spirit of this won't work.

Just for reference, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

```
create table some_test_data
  (
    column_a varchar(10),
    column_b varchar(10)
  )

insert into some_test_data values ('TRA','ORIG');
insert into some_test_data values ('TRA','ORIG');
insert into some_test_data values ('TERM','_N');
insert into some_test_data values ('TRA','ORIG');
insert into some_test_data values ('ORIG-REV1','_N');
insert into some_test_data values ('ORIG-REV2','_N');

select * 
  from some_test_data
 where column_b <> '_N'
    or (
       column_a <> 'ORIG-REV1'
   and column_a <> 'ORIG-REV2'
       )
```

Comment: So: OR column_a NOT IN ('ORIG-REV1','ORIG-REV2')

Comment: @yotheguitou You'd hope. But since they deconstructed the NOT IN, in the question body. And since OP's tool doesn't support NOT() I figured to be on the safe side.

Comment: Sorry sorry. I was thinking it was not possible to do : NOT(B = '...' AND A IN (...))

Comment: @yotheguitou You very well might be right and NOT IN is supported. But it's very difficult to find documentation for something called "search" :).

Comment: @Error_2646 thank you , that it worked! the only option i didn't try from in where clause. Kept focus on the "column_b and"

Comment: @macieira Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

Lets do it one by one.

Your equation is

```
"COLUMN B"='_N' and "COLUMN  A" in ('ORIG-REV1','ORIG-REV2')
```

Which is equivalent to (Replace `IN` with `OR` and `=`)

```
"COLUMN B"='_N' 
and ("COLUMN  A"= 'ORIG-REV1' OR "COLUMN  A" = 'ORIG-REV2')
```

Now, let's apply negation on each condition and operators.

`=` will become `<>`

`OR` will become `AND` and vice-versa.

```
"COLUMN B" <> '_N' 
OR ("COLUMN  A" <> 'ORIG-REV1' AND "COLUMN  A" <> 'ORIG-REV2')
```